# Sharing in workgroup

Tags: windows-server-2008, workgroup

I want to share one folder from the server which is at work-group (not a domain system) for 10 users. every user has a different name. And I want to assign permissions  on a folder by user name. Is this scenario possible to work group?? Like we do same thing on domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a server that is not in the domain, but each user that needs access to the server will have to have a local account on the server.  If the usernames and passwords on the server are the same as the usernames and passwords on the domain, users will not get a login prompt when trying to access the server (i.e., Windows uses pass-through authentication, passing the domain username and password to the server, and if the credentials match a local account, access is granted accordingly).

If the user credentials do not match, the user will be presented with a login prompt.  Unfortunately, there is no way for a user to change their password on that server without logging in to it via RDP or console, or using other tools (see http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/1966-how-to-change-local-user-or-admin-passwords-on-remote-computers) so keeping passwords synchronized with the domain accounts can be problematic.

Permissions cannot be assigned to domain accounts since the server isn't a member of the domain.  Permissions will have to be assigned to the local users (or groups).